# Running tabBarItem code before view controller loads

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a tabbar app, and I put the following code in my view controllers:

```
let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

if orientation == .portrait {
    self.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -17.0) 
} else if orientation == .landscapeLeft || orientation == .landscapeRight {
    self.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0.0) // updating the title positon
}
```

This changes the offsets for my tab bar items' titles. In landscape, the offsets get reversed automatically, so I have to do it manually. This works, but only when you actually click on a tab bar item and it loads a view controller.

I want to load this code at the start, so it changes the offset when you launch the app (before the view controllers load). Here are some pictures to describe what I said:

When you first launch the app, this is the first view controller, so it loads that code and it changes position:

[image: initial result - only the first tab bar item is in the correct position]

If you tap on the second item, the second view controller loads and it changes position as well.

[image: second tab bar item in the correct position]

I need to load this code for each tab bar item, so it looks like this from the start:

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should subclass `UITabBarController` and execute the code that changes the title position adjustment after the controller loads (`viewDidLoad`) and every time the view size/orientation changes (`viewWillTransition`).

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tabBarItemsUI()
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self] context in
            self?.tabBarItemsUI()
        })
    }

    fileprivate func tabBarItemsUI() {
        let isLandscape = [.landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight].contains(UIDevice.current.orientation)
        tabBar.items?.forEach { $0.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: isLandscape ? 0 : -17) }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, im a bit unfamiliar with xcode coming from android. So thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code in `viewWillAppear()` function.

Comment: I did But it still only runs when you click the actual tabbaritem